# Django value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project. I want to press button and date time save to database, but there is an error.

#### File *view.py*

```
        def confirm_order(request, pk):
            get_emp = get_object_or_404(Employee, pk=pk)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                new_end_date = request.POST['new_date']
                get_emp.end_date = new_end_date
                get_emp.save()
                return redirect('all_emp')     
            else:
                context = {
                    'get_emp': get_emp,
                }
                return render(request, 'confirm_order.html', context)
```

```
ValidationError at /confirm_order/5/
['“Feb. 29, 2023, 3:48 p.m.” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/confirm_order/5/
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
['“Feb. 29, 2023, 3:48 p.m.” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
Exception Location: /home/gino/PycharmProjects/office_emp_proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py, line 1567, in to_python
Raised during:  emp_app.views.confirm_order
Python Executable:  /home/gino/PycharmProjects/office_emp_proj/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.10.12
Python Path:    
['/home/gino/PycharmProjects/office_emp_proj',
 '/home/gino/PycharmProjects/office_emp_proj',
 '/snap/pycharm-professional/364/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/gino/PycharmProjects/office_emp_proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/snap/pycharm-professional/364/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Mon, 01 Jan 2024 09:10:25 +0800
```

[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1OBx.png)

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: please don't just post a bunch of terminal output if the error can be found in the first few lines and put a bit more effort into your grammar and spelling. it's horrible to look at :)

Comment: The date you're passing is in the wrong format. You can either update the server to support that format (but I wouldn't recommend it for a format like that) or you can update the client to send a correctly formatted date (which should be very easy with `Date.toISOString()`)

Comment: I can save Y:m:d to db but can't save h:m:s to db,Why？Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error might be due to the format of the date you're trying to save. Django expects dates in a specific format (YYYY-MM-DD) and if the date you're trying to save doesn't match this format, it will throw an error.

You can use Python's datetime module to parse the date from the request and convert it to the correct format. Here's how you can do it:

```
from datetime import datetime

def confirm_order(request, pk):
    get_emp = get_object_or_404(Employee, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_end_date_str = request.POST['new_date']
        # Parse the date from the request
        new_end_date = datetime.strptime(new_end_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        get_emp.end_date = new_end_date
        get_emp.save()
        return redirect('all_emp')     
    else:
        context = {
            'get_emp': get_emp,
        }
        return render(request, 'confirm_order.html', context)
```

`datetime.strptime` is used to parse the date from the request. The second argument to strptime is the format of the date in the request. You should replace `%Y-%m-%d` with the format of the date you're receiving in the request.

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: I can save Y:m:d to db but  can't save h:m:s to db,Why？Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy